# What is the difference between addActionListener(this) and addActionListener(new ActionListener)?

Tags: java, event-handling, actionlistener

I want to add event handling to buttons- and I noticed that there are two ways to do this.

1. Implement the ActionListener interface and then append event listeners to the buttons.

Example:

```
countButton.addActionListener(this);
```

And the in the ActionPerformed method will run to display the result.

1. Do not implement the ActionListener interface and instead do this:

   ```
   countButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
       {
           //Execute when button is pressed
           System.out.println("You clicked the button");
       }
   });
   ```

How does the second method work exactly?????!!!

Thanks!

Comment: It does the same thing, except the second one is an anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to define a second class for the first approach. You just need to add the 
`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` method inside your class and do whatever you want there, after you make your class implement ActionListener. You could use a second class if you wanted to, but it is not necessary. The disadvantage is that you need to specify the source of the event with long if statements in order to take the appropriate action if you have more than one JButtons i.e.

The second approach is adding an anonymous inner ActionListener to every component. It is a more Object Oriented approach, since you have a clearer separation of the functionality of your widgets. It is of advantage to define an additional method called inside each actionPerformed, in order to be able to use **this** freely and refer to the containing class:

```
countButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        doCountButtonAction(e);
        // "this" here would refer to the ActionListener (not that useful)
    }
});
```

and implement the method:

```
private void doCountButtonAction(ActionEvent e) {
   // do whatever you need to here
   // using "this" here refers to the containing class (i.e. JFrame, JPanel or whatever)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not exactly on listeners as it is on how interfaces work and how you can instantiate a class in Java. Here's some finer points:

1. Basicaly, what the JButton class offers you is a way to declare a class who's one particular method will be called when an event is triggered on the button, like when it is clicked. If you look at the Javadocs for JButton and ActionListener, you will now how they work:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#addActionListener(java.awt.event.ActionListener)

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html

What you can do here in the most old fashioned way possible is to create a class that will be triggered when someone clicks your button:

```
public class MyButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    System.out.println("Aww, you clicked!");    
    }
}
```

Now, once that's done, you can make an insance of it and add it as a listener to your button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("My button");
```

MyButtonActionListener myActionListener = new MyButtonActionListener ();
button.addActionListener(myActionListener);

On the other hand, in Java you can instantiate a class anonimousy, which means that instead of having a handler to it's instance (like myActionListener in the above code), you just instantiate it on the fly in the place you need it, and you'll have no handler to use it later. That's what's happening in your code: an ActionListener implementation is delcared on the fly as the parameter for the addActionListener method, that on the fly declaration also includes the statement that your anonymous instance is not just any class, but one that implements ActionListener, and such your anonymous declaration needs to give an implementation of the actionPerformed method.

A third option is to have a class that implements ActionListener (and the actionPerformed method), and inside that class, if you create a JButton and you want to pass it as listener an instance of the ecompasing class, you'll use "this" to reffer to that, as in :

```
public class MyButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {

private JButton button = new JButton();


public void init() {
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

public actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("u clicked!");
    }
}
```

There's alot of finer points to this discussion (as in how do you reffer to the "this" on a n anonymous class delcared inside an other class, and how do you reffer to the "this" of the encompassing class instance). I recommend that you read a book on the Sun Certified Java Programmer certification, it has a chapter dedicated to this

Answer (score 0):

That just creates an anonymous class that implements the actionPerformed method.  This way you don't have to define a new class for every place that you want to handle an event.

Answer (score 0):

It works the same way as the first technique i.e. The method expects an object which implement ActionListener interface. However, both techniques has its own merits and demerits. The first technique allows utilizing single object on the expense of cluttered if/else code because same method will be handling events for multiple buttons. The second technique allows cleaner separation of logic for each button on the expense of creating multiple anonymous objects (for each button).

Answer (score 0):

Either way, to add an ActionListener you need a class that implements the ActionListener interface (which defines a single method, `actionPerformed`).  `addActionListener(this)` implies that `this` implements that interface, and any action performed will call `this.actionPerformed`.

In the second case, what you're doing is creating a new, anonymous, class that implements the ActionListener interface.  When `countButton` is clicked, the `actionPerformed` method called is the one in the anonymous class.